ValueError: X has 16 features, but SVC is expecting 17 features as input in disease prediction system
I am trying multiple disease prediction system and among them the error occur when trying malaria disease prediction system using svm algorithm. I have no idea how to fix the problem since other 4 disease predictions have no problem. I am new to ML field and this is the first project , so if the problem is too easy please understand me .
Error message :
alueError: X has 16 features, but SVC is expecting 17 features as input.
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\HP\.conda\envs\DiseasePredictionSystem\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 584, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Multiple Disease Prediction System\multiple disease pred.py", line 404, in <module>
    malaria_prediction = malaria_model.predict([user_input])
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\HP\.conda\envs\DiseasePredictionSystem\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 820, in predict
    y = super().predict(X)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\HP\.conda\envs\DiseasePredictionSystem\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 433, in predict
    X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\HP\.conda\envs\DiseasePredictionSystem\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 613, in _validate_for_predict
    X = self._validate_data(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\HP\.conda\envs\DiseasePredictionSystem\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 588, in _validate_data
    self._check_n_features(X, reset=reset)
File "C:\Users\HP\.conda\envs\DiseasePredictionSystem\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 389, in _check_n_features
    raise ValueError(

UI in the streamlit :
#Malaria Prediction Page
if selected == 'Malaria Disease Prediction':

     #page title
     st.title('Malaria Prediction using ML')
     col1, col2, col3, col4 = st.columns(4)

     with col1:
         age = st.text_input('Enter Your Age')

     with col2:
         sex = st.text_input('Male or Female [0/1] Male=0, Female=1')
         
     with col3:
        fever = st.text_input('Do you have fever? [0/1] Yes=1, No=0')

     with col4:
         cold = st.text_input('Are you feeling cold?  [0/1] Yes=1, No=0')

     with col1:
         rigor = st.text_input('Do you feel rigor:high temperature and tremble with cold ?[0/1] Yes=1, No=0')

     with col2:
         fatigue = st.text_input('Do you feel fatigue?[0/1] Yes=1, No=0')

     with col3:
         headace = st.text_input('Do you feel headache?[0/1] Yes=1, No=0')

     with col4:
         bitter_tongue = st.text_input('Bitter tougue?[0/1] Yes=1, No=0')

     with col1:
         vomitting = st.text_input('Do you Vomit? [0/1] Yes=1, No=0')

     with col2:
         diarrhea = st.text_input('Diarrhea? [0/1] Yes=1, No=0')

     with col3:
         Convulsion = st.text_input('Have you ever muscular contract? [0/1] Yes=1, No=0')

     with col4:
         Anemia = st.text_input('Do you have anemia? [0/1] Yes=1, No=0')
         
     with col1:
        jundice = st.text_input('Do you have Jaundice? [0/1] Yes=1, No=0')
        
     with col2:
            cocacola_urine = st.text_input('Colour of urine is like cocacola? [0/1] Yes=1, No=0')
            
     with col3:
            hypoglycemia = st.text_input('Low in blood sugar level? [0/1] Yes=1, No=0')
            
     with col4:
            prostraction = st.text_input('Have you collapse? [0/1] Yes=1, No=0')
            
     with col1:
        hyperpyrexia = st.text_input('Body temperature up to 106.7°F or 41.5°C?[0/1] Yes=1, No=0')

#code for prediction
     user_input = [age, sex, fever, cold, rigor, fatigue, headace, bitter_tongue, vomitting, diarrhea, Convulsion, Anemia, jundice, cocacola_urine, prostraction, hyperpyrexia]

         user_input = [float(x) for x in user_input]

         malaria_prediction = malaria_model.predict([user_input])

         if malaria_prediction[0] == 1:
             hypertension_diagnosis = 'The person has malaria disease'
         else:
             hypertension_diagnosis = 'The person does not have  malaria disease'

     st.success(malaria_diagnosis)

The google colab code of the system:
Dataset

Your input was missing a feature hypoglycemia, resulting in 16 inputs rather than 17. Should be:
...
#code for prediction
     user_input = [age, sex, fever, cold, rigor, fatigue,
                   headace, bitter_tongue, vomitting, diarrhea,
                   Convulsion, Anemia, jundice, cocacola_urine,
                   hypoglycemia, #<---------- this was missing
                   prostraction, hyperpyrexia
                   ]
...

You might also need to change the input to a numpy array: model.predict( np.array([user_input]) ) rather than just model.predict([user_input]). But perhaps your UI handles that automatically.

I modified the code but it shows another error : C:\Users\HP.conda\envs\DiseasePredictionSystem\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:439: UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but SVC was fitted with feature names
warnings.warn(

That's a warning as opposed to an error; I think it should still run? You'd need to make sure that the order of the input features matches the order used in the training data.

The UI still run but doesn't get any output. Where should i know the order of training ? I just separated of the csv via the  code in colab . Thank you for answering .

In the code, column 0 is age and column 16 is hyperpyrexia. When you .predict(), the model expects them to be arranged the same way (first value is age, ..., last value is hyperpyrexia). I don't know about the empty output you're getting...I'm not familiar with the API you're using.
